# How do I create a widget that can be pushed and pushed with the appropriate animation? Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I need to create a widget that can be pushed from one state to another state and pushed back in the same way. But I don't quite understand how I can achieve this.[image][image][image][image]

I've been considering a solution through Animated Container but I'm not getting the desired result